# Compile module for 64 bits android devices with Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, arm64

I'm building a module for Android but I can't install it on 64 bits devices. 
I think I need to compile the module for `arm64` but I don't know how to. I tried adding `arm64-v8a` in manifest but it doesn't work I get the following :

```
[echo] Architectures in manifest: armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 arm64-v8a
[echo] Compiled binary architectures: armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86
```

Does anyone know **how to make titanium compile binary for arm64** ? 
Thanks ! ( it's a module for Moodstocks.com / image recognition, if someone is interested I will open source the code soon)

Comment: It isn't too much clear, you have placed the ABI in the manifest file of the module, or into the android manifest of timodule.xml?

Comment: I have placed the following in manifest file : 
`architectures: armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 arm64-v8a`

I tried to add <abi>arm64-v8a</abi> in timodule.xml but it does not seem to change anything

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Fokke ! And do you have any ideas ? :) Maybe I'm going the wrong way .. I'm new to module development to be honest it's my first one !

Comment: One of our engineers is looking into your question and will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll release the module on gitt.io as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

The Titanium core library is only compiled for armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86, so I don't believe it supports compiling 3rd-party modules for other ABI/architectures. The 32-bit library should run fine on a 64-bit device.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought but when I try to launch app with this module on a 64 bits device ( Huawei Honor : GEM-703L ) I get the following error : http://pastie.org/10800685

It's seems like a problem with TiVerify on arm64, do you have any ideas?

Anyway thanks for you quick answer !

Comment: Yes, that looks nasty! Looks like it's having issues loading tiverify native library on arm64. I've opened a bug report for it: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23228

Comment: Thanks for your help I will watch the jira report.